# Solving a system of 3 variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry, systems-of-equations

How to solve or what is the algorithm to solve a system of equations like this: 
$$\eqalign{
(x +\phantom{3} z)^2 + (y +\phantom{3} w)^2 &= 52\cr
(x + 3z)^2 + (y + 3w)^2 &= 296\cr
(x -\phantom{3} z)^2 + (y -\phantom{3} w)^2 &= 8\cr
(x -2z)^2 + (y - 2w)^2 &= 61?
}$$

Comment: Thank a lot for any helpful answers!

Comment: Expand the 2nd one in this way: $(x+3z)^2=((x+z)+2z)^2$ and similar for the other part. This will help you combine the equations

Comment: Look at the first and third equations first.Can you add or subtract them to get anything nice?

Answer (score -1):

By trying to solve this equation (adding and subtracting first and third equations, putting results to fourth equation) I eventually got these:

$$\begin{cases}z^2+w^2=25\\
  x^2+y^2=5\\
 zx+wy=11\end{cases}$$

All of the given equations are the results of the equations I have provided. (You can check it).
And I found that the only integers which can solve the equation are:

$$x=2, y=1, z=4, w=3\quad\text{or}\quad
x=-2, y=-1, z=-4, w=-3$$

Comment: 1) Nowhere it states that the solutions must integers. 2) Reading the OP, writing down the passages seemed rather *crucial*. 3) The fact that a set of solutions fits the equation does not prove that you've found all of them. 4) $z2\neq z^2$